# How to fix an inventory dragging glitch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing some Sky Factory 3 with a friend on my server, when all of a sudden I can't drag any item, or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd> any item in my inventory, or out of it. I'm not lagging at all, because I can interact with blocks and stuff, but not items. Sometimes going into a singleplayer world and opening my inventory several times fixes it, but sometimes it doesn't, and I would have to restart my game. This normally takes a long time and is a real hassle, since Sky Factory 3 has tons of mods. It's happened on multiple occasions, and I would like to know a way to fix this permanently.
Thanks!

Comment: Your workaround is probably just a Placebo, I bet it does nothing. Also, obligatory upvote for reasonable modded MC question, because those always get one or two downvotes for no reason. Other than that, I'm afraid I can't help you.

Comment: It looks like a certain form of server lag. It's extremely easy to lag the server down to a crawl in modded Minecraft. Try to recall what sort of contraptions/machines/connections you've activated shortly before the problem began, and try to deactivate them.

Comment: Well, it actually started when I started playing, and also, I'm pretty sure it's not lag as my friend is actually way more laggier than me, and yet he still doesn't have this glitch

Comment: i'm pretty sure that since this is modded minecraft, it's considered off-topic.

Comment: @EarthToAccess You're half-right: it's about *technical support* for modded Minecraft. There is nothing inherently wrong with modded Minecraft.

Comment: isn't this technical support? OP's asking about a glitch in-game with the inventory.